# PHP MVC routing (mod_rewrite)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, model-view-controller

got some problems performing routings on my php MVC script. I'll provide you with the logs and code's that I've got available.

http://pastebin.com/gs05xFY0

as you can see I've got the `LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so` uncommented as well as `AllowOverride All` so that should be fine now.
Here's my access.log file (Parental Advice)

```
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:46:36 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:14 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:17 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:19 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:20 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:31 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/index/home/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:38 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/lol HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:50:40 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:51:00 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/ HTTP/1.1" 200 -
127.0.0.1 - - [19/May/2015:23:51:16 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/fuuuck HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2015:00:03:23 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index/fuuuck HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2015:00:03:30 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2015:00:08:54 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2015:00:08:57 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/home/index HTTP/1.1" 404 1094
127.0.0.1 - - [20/May/2015:00:16:42 +0200] "GET /projects/mvc/public/phpinfo.php HTTP/1.1" 200 100480
```

so I keep getting a 404 FILE NOT FOUND error...
This is the actuall .htaccess -file

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /projects/mvc/public

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Here is my PHP code.

```
// public/index.php
<?php 

require_once '../app/init.php';

$app = new App;

?>
// app/init.php
<?php

require_once 'core/App.php';
require_once 'core/Controller.php';

?>
// core/App.php
<?php
class App {
    protected $controller = 'home';

    protected $method = 'index';

    protected $params = [];

    public function __construct() {
        $this->parseUrl();
    }

    public function parseUrl() {
            if( isset( $_GET['url'] ) ) {
                echo $_GET['url'];
            }
    }
}

?>
// core/Controller.php
<?php

class Controller {

}

?>
// controllers/home.php
<?php

class Home extends Controller {

    public function index()
    {
        echo "home/index";
    }
}

?>
```

Here are my loaded modules fetched from phpinfo()

```
core mod_win32 mpm_winnt http_core mod_so mod_access_compat mod_actions mod_alias mod_allowmethods mod_asis mod_auth_basic mod_authn_core mod_authn_file mod_authz_core mod_authz_groupfile mod_authz_host mod_authz_user mod_autoindex mod_cgi mod_dir mod_env mod_include mod_isapi mod_log_config mod_mime mod_negotiation mod_rewrite mod_setenvif mod_php5
```

EDIT: Here is the error log as well :)

http://pastebin.com/d7793S1H

I'm on a Win8 using EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC11. Please let me know if you need some further information, I've been pulling my hair on this one for a while now :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that you have an extremely similar to the case I was having in this question:

[Htaccess Public Folder Rewrite Rule](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33008662/1745715)

Please compare with that answer, but I believe that adding this directory index at the top will be all you need:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
```