# Htaccess Public Folder Rewrite Rule

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I'm working on a little custom MVC project in PHP and am having some issues with the htaccess. Originally, my htaccess was routing all traffic to index.php in my root dir, and passing the remaining path as an argument. This was working perfectly with this code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
```

The problem I'm having now is that I need to move the index.php file into a /public directory. I scoured the internet for answers, and found a code snippet that *kinda* works in that it seems to get there as long as it is just hitting /, but as soon as the url becomes /register/ or anything else it just 404's.

```
# Get rid of /public/ in the URL, and route all requests through
# the Index.php file
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ /public/index.php?path=$1 [NC,L,QSA]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/public/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*?)/?$ public/$1 [L]
```

I know that last line makes no sense in when there is the rewrite to index.php with ?path that seems proper to me (at least it passes the argument like I want!) but without both these lines it doesn't seem to work, and I've been trial-and-erroring this for hours. Hopefully someone can help out! Cheers!

Comment: Have you tried RewriteBase directive? It will prepend the uri you set to your RewriteBase rules. This would mean you can use the same .htaccess, just add the RewriteBase directive above with a value of "/public"

Comment: Hi, .htaccess and php are seperate things :) php has nothing to do with this :)

Comment: As per @MarkSkayff, I tried it this way: http://pastebin.com/PUmfHgLK (note the last line commented out again) With the last line commented out, I get a directory listing when trying to access /, and any other url I get a 404.

Comment: As per your question @anubhava, your suggestion: http://pastebin.com/Rkbkv0cm yields a directory listing for /, and a 404 for anything past that.

Comment: @Epodax agreed they're not the same, nor do they rely on each other. I added the PHP tag mainly because it was suggested (I figure for how many times the word showed up in my question). Do you think this is unrelated enough to PHP that it would be more helpful to remove the tag?

Comment: @anubhava your second suggestion (and the combination of both suggestions possible by commenting out lines 4, 7, & 8) all yield the same result as the first. Dir listing for /, otherwise 404. I'll mention that I'm positive that none of these 404s are being generated by the PHP itself, they are all from apache.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep only this content in your .htaccess:

```
DirectoryIndex index.php
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/?$ public/ [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ public/?path=$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Thanks, I have the same issue, with you block code, my project works! c: